# Solution differential equation $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ax+bx^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ax+bx^3$$

I tried the following:
$$\frac{d^2x}{ax+bx^3}=dt^2$$

But I'm not sure how to continue. Can I use $d^2x$ the same as $dx^2$ and use partial fraction decomposition to work out the left side of the equation? Like this:
$$
\begin{split}
\iint{\frac{1}{ax+bx^3}d^2x}&=\iint{dt^2}\\
\frac{1}{b}\iint{\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}+\frac{C}{x-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}d^2x} &= \frac{t^2}{2}+c_1t+c_2
\end{split}
$$

 But am I using $d^2x$ correctly here? If not, how can I solve this equation?

Comment: No you can not you missunderstand dx^2 which is a aymbol for the second derivative and not dx*dx

Comment: Wolfram alpha obtain [this solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%28t%29%3Dax%2Bbx%5E3).

Comment: @callculus nasty, with elliptic functions. Somehow I doubt this is nicely solvable, $x^3$ makes it wildly non-linear

Comment: Duffing's equation

Comment: I think it will be good to know the context in which you have this equation. May be it can be solved easier knowing the context. Is it a given equation of acceleration?

Comment: The context of the equation is as follows: I am reviewing a simple pendulum, giving the following equation of motion: mr^2x'' = mgr*sin(x) with x the angle with the vertical axis. sin(x) is often simplified to sin(x)=x, but I'm trying to solve it more accurately by expanding the series to sin(x)=x-x^3/3!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ax+bx^3$$
You can reduce the order. Multiply by $2x'$ both sides:
$$2x'x''=2axx'+2bx^3x'$$
After integration, it gives:
$$x'^2=ax^2+\dfrac 12bx^4+C_1$$
It's separable ( maybe not easy to integrate again).

---

Note that:
$$dx^2=2xdx \ne d^2x$$
I am not sure that $d^2x$ alone has any meaning. So no you can't equate $dx^2$ and $d^2x$.You can write this:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{dx'}{dt}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the undamped, unforced Duffing equation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) gives an explanation of the method of solving it

You can multiply the whole thing by $dx/dt$ to get an expression that can be integrated to a first order equation and then solved.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $b=\pm2$, as you can achieve by rescaling $x$.

The equation is autonomous, so with $p:=\dot x$,

$$pp'=ax\pm 2x^3$$ and by integration

$$p^2=ax^2\pm x^4+c,$$

which is separable.

Then

$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\pm x^4+ax^2+c}}=\pm dt.$$

Analytical integration is possible, but difficult.